# expose cluster running private subnet to an internet facing load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

I have a cluster v 1.15 running in AWS. I have a service that I use from within the pod that I'm not in control of and that requires whitelisting via IP address so I wanted to get a static IP  use NAT gateway IP. The cluster is currently running in a public subnet but I'm planning to move the node groups to a private subnet to use the NAT IP. The issue is I have an internet facing Elastic load balancer used by the front end pods in the eks accessed via HTTP and HTTPS that is already attached to the public subnet and I'm afraid that the front end will become unreachable if I move the nodes to a private subnet. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide more details? Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor? What did you try? Why did you delete so much information from this question?

Comment: I was drafting the question and accidentally saved it. I've corrected it now

Answer (score 0):

Noticed you have changed your question. Anyway, you can whitelist using the EIP that associated with the NAT.